# UICollectionView not appearing in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, xcode6-beta6

When I build my project the screen just appears white in the simulator (where a collection view is black) and none of the cells that I want to appear either of course.

I am using xcode6-beta6 and this is for ios (ipad).

So I am trying to populate a collection view with labels. In my story board I have the view controller with just the collection view inside it with one cell which I placed a label inside. I know I have the identifier and tag properly set in the story board and my viewcontroller code. I know I also have my dataSource and delegate outlets properly set up. I have been following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiiN9oFH3vE however it is in xcode 5 and objective-c so I don't know if there is something that is completely different in swift/xcode6  that I am not doing.

Here is my code

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var testArray:[String]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    testArray = ["hello","world","hola","mmg","me","la"]
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!) -> Int{
    return 1
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return testArray.count
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell!{
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FirstCollectionViewCell

    var label = cell.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel
    label.text = testArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the `UICollectionView` Delegate and Data Source as `self` anywhere? I don't see it in your code and that could be the problem. You probably need it in your `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not follow. Set it as self? I have not come across this I don't think in any tutorials.

Comment: Something like self.collectionView.delegate = self;

Comment: I get the error "(UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection:Int)->Int does not have a member named 'delegate'"

I also got a similar error for self.collectionView.dataSource = self

Comment: U should be doing this in viewdidload

Comment: Yes, I am. Also, xcode is not providing autofill for me which makes me question is this still a thing for swift? Perhaps a different syntax is needed? I'm googling it.

Comment: Do you have an outlet to your collection view?

Comment: No, just made it. `@IBOutlet weak var viewOutlet: UICollectionView!` just above `viewDidLoad()`. Same result when building. And same error for `self.collectionView.delegate = self`.

Comment: I set the delegate and datasource with the story board though (ctrl + drag to controller and select outlets). Isn't that enough?

Comment: So it'd be viewOutlet.delegate. I'm not sure if u need both but that could be the issue.